# Why so may files with TCL download

Tags: tcl

I am absolute beginner with no knowledge of TCL. I need to write few TCL scripts, in Win7 environment.
I downloaded the following:
[downloads.activestate.com/ActiveTCL/releases/8.6.4.1/ActiveTcl8.6.4.1.299124-win32-x86_64-threaded.exe](http://downloads.activestate.com/ActiveTcl/releases/8.6.4.1/ActiveTcl8.6.4.1.299124-win32-x86_64-threaded.exe)

After download,
I see following files in *C:\TCL\bin*

> tclsh86.exe,teacup.exe,tkcon.tcl,wish86.exe and some dll's.

I also see the following in Windows start menu:

[image]

I can  relate tclsh86.exe to Tlcsk86 and wish86.exe to Wish86 in the screenshot above .

I have couple of queries:

1. What is the purpose of so many executables in the folder. I am assuming I just need Tclsh86 for running TCL scripts?
2. What is the best way to execute the TCL scripts? create them in Notepad/Notepad++ and run them from TCL shell? before doing that, do i need to setup anything like paths etc in environment variables?
3. I downloaded free version of Komodo IDE but that did not have standard layout like FILE,Run etc , so seems useless. Can anyone suggest IDE to run the TCL scripts ,similar to PyCharm ?

Thanks
sedy

Comment: IDE recommendations — well, _any_ software system recommendations — are formally off-topic for Stack Overflow. Fortunately, you ask questions that have definitive answers as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 1. What are those files?

- **wish86**: Well, wish.
- **tclsh86**: Console application.
- **teacup**: Install additional packages from a central repository.
- **tkcon.tcl**: Tcl Shell written in Tcl. IMHO better than wish for interactive development.
- **tcl86.dll**: You can embed Tcl in your own programs written in e.g. C, this dll is required for that.
- **tk86.dll**: You can also embed Tk or load it into an existing Tcl interpreter.
- **base-tcl8.6-thread-win32-ix86.exe**: A [BaseKit](http://wiki.tcl.tk/15985).
- **base-tcl8.6-thread-win32-ix86.dll**: A BaseDll. Basically the same as a BaseKit, just as dll.
- **base-tk8.6-thread-win32-ix86.exe**: Also a BaseKit, just with Tk embedded too.

### 2. What setup is needed?

On your machine, the Tcl installer should have taken care of everything, PATH, file association etc.

If you want to run your scripts on other machines that don't have Tcl installed, it's a bit more complex, I suggest using a [StarKit](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3661)

### 3. Recommend an IDE.

I write my scripts in notepad++ and source them into tkcon. Works for me.
Other than that I can't give you a recommendation.

Comment: Thanks. So _tkcon_ is basically similar to _tclsh_ except that it has more extensions?

Comment: Similar to wish, and it has more tools, like tabs, `edit procname`, which lets you edit a proc in an external window and other useful stuff.

Comment: There are a number of IDEs that support Tcl (e.g., Eclipse with the DLTK, Komodo) but I find myself satisfied with ordinary Emacs and an interactive Tcl session for testing things out. People's mileage varies a lot in this area.

Comment: @user915783 tclsh is not really the console app. It is THE tcl interpreter in the same way bash is the bash interpreter and node is the node.js interpreter and php is the php interpreter. wish on the other hand is a tcl interpreter that does a `package require Tk` automatically and adds a `vwait` to the end of your script automatically. On Windows though, there is a difference between console app and GUI app (this is not true on other platforms where GUI apps are just console apps that happen to create windows) so on Windows tclsh is compiled as a console app and wish is compiled as a GUI app